# How add depedency for PyElementVisitor for Intellij Idea plugin?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

**The goal**

1. create a plugin for Python files
2. debug this plugin with Intellij Idea (not PyCharm) for 2 reasons: a) IntelliJ Idea is the main development IDE b) I do not have/want an additional license for PyCharm
3. The plugin should rely on [python-psi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jetbrains.intellij.python/python-psi) classes like `com.jetbrains.python.psi.PyElementVisitor`.

**The problem**

1. If I use [pycharm basics](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/blob/main/product_specific/pycharm_basics) (see build.gradle.kts) file project I will have `com.jetbrains.python.*` class but I get pycharm running when I run debug.
2. I can modify [java inspection](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/blob/main/comparing_string_references_inspection) (see build.gradle.kts) file e.g. add Python plugin but here I am stuck because dependencies for `com.jetbrains.python.*` are not loaded.

**What I have tried**

I have tried something the like ([build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/blob/main/comparing_string_references_inspection/build.gradle.kts)):

```
intellij {
  version.set("2022.2.5")
  plugins.set(listOf(
          "com.intellij.java",
          "com.jetbrains.intellij.python:python-psi:202.7319.50"
  ))
}
```

Something like `com.intellij.python` or `Pythonid` also does not work.

The pycharm basics [build.gradle.kts](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-code-samples/blob/main/product_specific/pycharm_basics/build.gradle.kts) version:

```
intellij {
  version.set("2022.2.5")
  type.set("PY")                   //here PyCharm is "selected"
  plugins.set(listOf("Pythonid"))  //even if add this into Inllij version I will have plugin not found
  downloadSources.set(false)
}
```

So the question is - how to modify java inspection code and be able to run Intellij Idea with `com.jetbrains.python.*` classes?

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.